# Unable to load image with Picasso in Android Studio 3.4.2

Tags: android, kotlin, picasso

I'm trying the example in the docs to load an image

```
val img = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView)
Picasso.get().load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(img)
```

It's not loading the image.

Here's my `activity_main.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editText" android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="59dp" android:layout_marginStart="59dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText"/>
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="Name"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginLeft="89dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="89dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="217dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"/>
    <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
            android:layout_width="224dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView" tools:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_marginTop="208dp" android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editText" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="80dp"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I'm new to android dev -- any tips on how to debug/solve this issue would be super helpful!

Edit:  I I have set internet permissions:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

and the problem still persists :(

I even added a listener:

```
       val picasso = Picasso.Builder(this)
            .listener { _, _, e ->
                run {
                    println("fuck")
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
            .build()
```

And no stacktrace got printed out, and yet the image still doesn't load. Sigh.

My `build.gradle`

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.31'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

### Solution

The problem was, I was trying to load the image from within an `executor` function. There's a check in picasso source that allows for image loads to happen only within the `main` function

```
  public void into(ImageView target, Callback callback) {
    long started = System.nanoTime();
    checkMain();
```

(I'm curious why the app never threw a stacktrace though...I'm guessing it was probably suppressed by a dependency or something?)

Comment: if you are using ProGuard you should follow Picasso's git tutorial [here](https://github.com/square/picasso#proguard)

Comment: @Ben Shmeul I didn't explicitly opt into ProGuard, so I don't think I'm using it, but will check anyway

Comment: Your `ImageView` height is set to 0. I would recommend changing width and height to `wrap_content`

Answer (score -1):

Remove `src attribute` from the imageView in xml

This line

```
 android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
```

Answer (score -1):

I use Piccaso library : `implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'`

Give internet permission in Manifest file.

Modify your java code only:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView=findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Picasso.with(this).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
    }
}
```

Comment: Or you can also use Piccaso like this way:
Picasso.with(context)
        .load(''http_url")
        .placeholder(R.drawable.user_thumbnail_big)
        .error(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
        .into(imageView);

Comment: `.with(context)` has been long ago replaced with `.get()`. That is not a solution.